# JSR352 - JBERET - How to check java batch program job log?

Tags: logging, jsr352, jberet

I am trying to run a JSR352 java batch program in Java SE mode using JBERET implementation. I can see my main() method getting executed. It is in this main() method i get handle of a job operator and starting the job.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LoggingConfig logConfiguration = new LoggingConfig();

    logger.info("Begining Batch with JBeret approach");

    JobOperator jo = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
    long id = jo.start("PilotJob", null);

    logger.info("End of Batch");

}
```

but, I do not see any log statements inside my reader, processor, writer or listeners getting printed.

I have a logging.properties defined and loaded from my projects src/main/resources/META-INF folder. The log statements in my main() method is getting printed according to it but, the log statements in my reader/writer/processor and listeners aren't printing at all.

```
public class LoggingConfig {
    public LoggingConfig() {
        try {
            // Load a properties file from class path that way can't be achieved
            // with java.util.logging.config.file

              final LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager(); 
              try (final InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/logging.properties")) 
              {
                  logManager.readConfiguration(is);
              }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while reading Log configuration file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Why isn't my log statements (java log library) in my java batch program to be printed ?***

Here are the logs from the main() method. I can clearly see that a job has been started but, not sure why the log statements of the batch program isn't getting printed.

```
    INFO: App Begining Batch with JBeret approach - v1.0
    INFO: org.jboss.weld.Version WELD-000900: 2.2.15 (Final)
    INFO: org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap WELD-ENV-000014: Falling back to Java Reflection for bean-discovery-mode="annotated" discovery. Add org.jboss:jandex to the classpath to speed-up startup.
    INFO: org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
    WARN: org.jboss.weld.Interceptor WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
    WARN: org.jboss.weld.Interceptor WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
    DEBUG: org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap WELD-000100: Weld initialized. Validating beans
    DEBUG: org.jboss.weld.Reflection WELD-000620: interface javax.enterprise.inject.Intercepted is not declared @Target(METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE). Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.
    DEBUG: org.jboss.weld.Reflection WELD-000620: interface javax.enterprise.inject.Decorated is not declared @Target(METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE). Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.        
    FINE: javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime Loaded BatchContainerServiceProvider with className = org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl
    TRACE: org.jberet JBERET000022: resume is not implemented for local transactions
    DEBUG: org.jberet JBERET000017: Persisted org.jberet.runtime.JobInstanceImpl@6 with id 6
    DEBUG: org.jberet JBERET000017: Persisted org.jberet.runtime.JobExecutionImpl@6 with id 6
    INFO: App End of Batch
```

Here is a Listener code which has both a Sysout and Log statement. Both of them aren't getting printed in my Eclipse console.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.batch.api.listener.AbstractJobListener;

public class PilotLibJobListener extends AbstractJobListener {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("PilotLibJobListener");   

    public void beforeJob() {
        BatchListenerRecorder.batchListenersCountDownLatch.countDown();
        System.out.println("Before Job");
        logger.info("MyJobListener.beforeJob");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob() {
        BatchListenerRecorder.batchListenersCountDownLatch.countDown();
        logger.info("MyJobListener.afterJob");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To query job execution status, you can just call the appropriate API on `JobOperator`, e.g., `public JobExecution getJobExecution(long executionId)`. The returned `JobExecution` object contains the latest data.

For job repository, you can choose in-memory job repository, if a jdbc job repository is too heavy-weight for your app. But with the default H2 database, you can configure to have embedded, or file-based H2 database, instead of the client-server mode, in order to limit resource consumption.

For logging issues, can you create a [JIRA issue](https://issues.jboss.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JBERET), or [github issue](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/issues), and attach a reproducible test app?

Comment: my jberet properties have a H2 DB configured as job repo but, my issue is more towards the log statements within my java batch program not getting printed. I can see that the log statements in main program getting printed but, not the ones in the jsr352 classes (reader/writer/processor/listener)

Comment: I have tried setting the system property org.jboss.logging.provider as suggested in this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272789 but, still not working. i have created a github issue https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/issues/102 with this problem